# Correction symbols used for mathematical texts

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, notation, mathematical-writing

When proof reading and correcting a mathematical text, I sometimes see people use special notation symbols in the margin to indicate correction, deletion, replacement and so on. Is there any standard for the correction symbols used?

Comment: http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~mathbio/links/refs/proofmarks.pdf

Comment: @CarloBeenakker wow, perfect. I think that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to mathematics. (It may, though I am not sure, be on-topic on some other SE sites, such as [academia.se], [writers.se] or [english.se])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Chicago Manual of Style**, 12 edition, p. 71, Proofreader's Marks.